# Where WordPress install is located on Google Cloud Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: wordpress, kubernetes

I have **Wordpress** run as an **app container** in Google Cloud Kubernetes Cluster.
I've ruined my site a bit by wrong modifications of theme's **functions.php** file. So now i would like to remove my bad code to make site working. Hoever I can not find where Wordpress is located.
As all I need is to remove couple lines of PHP code I thought it might be easier to do it right from the SSH command line without playing with SFTP and keys (sorry I'm newby in WordPress/Sites in general)
This how it looks like in Google Cloud Console

**Wordpress install**

[image: Wordpress App]

**Google Cloud Console: my cluster**

[image: Google Cloud Console screenshot]

I'm connecting to cluster through SSH by pressing "Connect" button.
And... tada! I see NO "/var/www/html" in "var" folder! ".../www/html" folder is not exists/visible even under root

[image: Contents on VAR folder]

Can someone help me with finding WordPress install, please :)

Here is the output for `$ kubectl describe pod market-engine-wordpress-0 mypod -n kalm-system` comand

```
Name:         market-engine-wordpress-0
Namespace:    kalm-system
Priority:     0
Node:         gke-cluster-1-default-pool-6c5a3d37-sx7g/10.164.0.2
Start Time:   Thu, 25 Jun 2020 17:35:54 +0300
Labels:       app.kubernetes.io/component=wordpress-webserver
              app.kubernetes.io/name=market-engine
              controller-revision-hash=market-engine-wordpress-b47df865b
              statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name=market-engine-wordpress-0
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Running
IP:           10.36.0.17
IPs:
  IP:           10.36.0.17
Controlled By:  StatefulSet/market-engine-wordpress
Containers:
  wordpress:
    Container ID:   docker://32ee6d8662ff29ce32a5c56384ba9548bdb54ebd7556de98cd9c401a742344d6
    Image:          gcr.io/cloud-marketplace/google/wordpress:5.3.2-20200515-193202
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://gcr.io/cloud-marketplace/google/wordpress@sha256:cb4515c3f331e0c6bcca5ec7b12d2f3f039fc5cdae32f0869abf19238d580575
    Port:           80/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Mon, 29 Jun 2020 15:37:38 +0300
      Finished:     Mon, 29 Jun 2020 15:40:08 +0300
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  774

  Environment:
      POD_NAME:       market-engine-wordpress-0 (v1:metadata.name)
      POD_NAMESPACE:  kalm-system (v1:metadata.namespace)
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-4f6xq (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  market-engine-wordpress-pvc:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  market-engine-wordpress-pvc-market-engine-wordpress-0
    ReadOnly:   false
  apache-config:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      market-engine-wordpress-config
    Optional:  false
  config-map:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      market-engine-wordpress-config
    Optional:  false
  default-token-4f6xq:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-4f6xq
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       Burstable
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                       From                                               Message
  ----     ------     ----                      ----                                               -------
  Warning  Unhealthy  8m33s (x9023 over 2d15h)  kubelet, gke-cluster-1-default-pool-6c5a3d37-sx7g  Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 500
  Warning  BackOff    3m30s (x9287 over 2d15h)  kubelet, gke-cluster-1-default-pool-6c5a3d37-sx7g  Back-off restarting failed container
```

Comment: This is exactly what one should not do! If you have your theme as plugin in a PV then just update that and do a Kubectl apply.

Comment: @ArmandoBallaci I do agree It wans't a good idea. The whole site including WP-admin section is not available so I can not update theme/change through admin pannel. BTW what is PV? :)

Comment: A kubernetes Persistent Volume. That is where you would store custom data for your WP app...

Comment: At the moment then I deployed the app container with Wordpress I had no kubernetes Persistent Volume. Now I've created kubernetes Persistent Volume here https://console.cloud.google.com/filestore/. And I have questions :) 1) how to check contents of PV? 2) If PV wasn't existed at deploying Worpress app stage newly created PV is supposed to be emplty... Right?

Comment: @ArmandoBallaci I'm trying to get the list of all pos by running a command `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces` and there is a pod `market-engine-wordpress-0`. Then I'm trying to run a remote shell `kubectl exec -it  market-engine-wordpress-0 -- sh` it says **Error from server (NotFound): pods "market-engine-wordpress-0" not found** what is wrong? :)

Comment: You ssh into a container not in a pod. The pod may have more containers. Use the dashboard for easier access I would say...

Comment: @ArmandoBallaci i'm sorry for asking dumb questions :) I wouldn't ask If I was able to get the gist easily :) But how to get access to right pod from dashboard?

Comment: hey, np. click on the pod then you have on the right the logs and shell icons. Click on the shell and select the right container over the htlm console :)

Comment: @ArmandoBallaci Well... Kubernets Engine -> Workloads -> Click on market-engine-wordpress object -> scroll down to Managed pods section and click on market-engine-wordpress-0 and then connect to Kubectl command line (please refer to screenshot) imgur.com/a/2KnHgKh No "/var/www/html" folder visible (even under root). How to connect to right pod in a right way? :)

Comment: Please, can you update your question and include the output for `kubectl describe pod market-engine-wordpress-0 mypod`?

Comment: I'm reproducing your scenario in my lab ans will get back to you.

Comment: For me `kubectl exec -ti market-engine-wordpress-0 -c wordpress -- bash` works fine. Can you try please?

Comment: You can't because your pod is on constant BackOff state. In other words, it's failing and it was restarted 9287 times since you deployed it.

Comment: @mWatney Does it mean that no hope to get site restored?

Comment: Did you manage to follow my instructions and get it to work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216901/discussion-between-mwatney-and-0leg).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you described, your application is crashing because of a change you have made in the code. This is making your website to fail and your pod is configured to check if the website is running fine and if not, the container will be restarted. The configuration that makes it happen is the LivenessProbe and the ReadinessProbe.

The problem here is that prevents you from fixing the problem.

The good news is that your data is saved under `/var/www/html` and this directory is on a external storage.

So, the easiest solution is to create a new pod and attach this storage to this pod. Problem is that this storage cannot be mounted on more than one container at the same time.

Creating this new pod, requires you to temporarily remove your wordpress pod. I know, it may be scary but we will recreate it after.

I reproduced your scenario and tested these steps. So Let's start. (All steps as mandatory)

Before we start, let's save your `market-engine-wordpress` manifest:

```
$ kubectl get statefulsets market-engine-wordpress -o yaml > market-engine-wordpress.yaml
```

Delete your wordpress statefulset:

```
$ kubectl delete statefulsets market-engine-wordpress
```

This commands delete the instruction that creates your wordpress pod.

Now, let's create a new pod using the following manifest:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: fenix 
  namespace: kalm-system  
spec:
  volumes:
  - name: market-engine-wordpress-pvc
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: market-engine-wordpress-pvc-market-engine-wordpress-0    
  containers:
  - name: ubuntu
    image: ubuntu
    command: ['sh', '-c', "sleep 36000"]
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /var/www/html
      name: market-engine-wordpress-pvc
      subPath: wp
```

To create this pod, save this content in a file as `fenix.yaml` and run the following command:

```
$ kubectl apply -f fenix.yaml
```

Check if the pod is ready:

```
$ kubectl get pods fenix
NAME         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
fenix        1/1     Running   0          5m
```

From this point, you can connect to this pod and fix your `functions.php` file:

```
$ kubectl exec -ti fenix -- bash
root@fenix:/# cd /var/www/html/wp-includes/
root@fenix:/var/www/html/wp-includes#
```

When you are done fixing your code, we can delete this pod and re-create your wordpress pod.

```
$ kubectl delete pod fenix 
pod "fenix" deleted
```

```
$ kubectl apply -f market-engine-wordpress.yaml 
statefulset.apps/market-engine-wordpress created
```

Check if the pod is ready:

```
$ kubectl get pod market-engine-wordpress-0 
NAME                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
market-engine-wordpress-0   2/2     Running   0          97s
```

If you need to exec into the wordpress container, your application uses the concept of multi-container pod and connecting to the right container requires you to indicate what container you want to connect.

To check how many containers and the name of which one you can run `kubectl get pod mypod -o yaml` or run `kubectl describe pod mypod`.

To finally exec into it, use the following command:

```
$ kubectl exec -ti market-engine-wordpress-0 -c wordpress -- bash
root@market-engine-wordpress-0:/var/www/html#
```

Comment: Wow!!!  Thank you very much for sparing your time on me (no irony, obviously time is most valuable thing we have)! That makes me belive more in humanity :)  I was following your instructions (btw it is really brilliant written explonation. I wish all docs/spes to be written in that way... separate thumbs up for Pod's name) but stuck (well... I'm almost hopeless...) on 1st connecting to pod Fenix

Comment: Thanks for the compliments. Let's solve this, what is the status of the pod Fenix? What you get when you try to connect to it?

Comment: Pod is ready. Result of `kubectl get pods fenix` command is 
`NAME    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
fenix   0/1     Pending   0          19s` but once I'm trying to connect to pod with `$ kubectl exec -ti fenix -- bash` it says `Error from server (BadRequest): pod fenix does not have a host assigned` (my guess: either something should be corrected in manifest or extra step is required to attach pod to host)

Comment: You need to check why it's pending using `kubectl describe pod fenix`. In the bottom you'll see the latest events and the reason why it's pending.

Comment: I assume you already deleted the statefulset right?

Comment: `Events:
  Type     Reason             Age                    From                Message
  ----     ------             ----                   ----                -------
  Normal   NotTriggerScaleUp  4m57s (x117 over 25m)  cluster-autoscaler  pod didn't trigger scale-up (it wouldn't fit if a new node is added):
  Warning  FailedScheduling   16s (x18 over 25m)     default-scheduler   persistentvolumeclaim "market-engine-wordpress-pvc-market-engine-wordpress-0" not found`

Comment: Okay, please update your question including the content of the file we created `market-engine-wordpress.yaml`